# Inscribing a regular tetrahedron in another regular tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, 3d, rotations, platonic-solids

Given a regular tetrahedron, make a uniformly scaled copy of it, such that both the original and the scaled copy (the scale factor is less than $1$) share the same centroid, and have the same orientation.  Then rotate the scaled copy such that its four vertices lie on the four faces of the original tetrahedron.

Suppose the scale factor is specified, what would be involved in finding the rotation matrix that when applied to the scaled down tetrahedron gives the desired result of inscribing it in the original tetrahedron?

Has this problem been studied?  Any citations, pointers, or hints are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** The range for the scale factor is $ \dfrac{1}{3} \le f \lt 1 $

Comment: Isn't it a rotation about the $z$ axis by $\pi/3$, then a rotation about any horizontal line by $\pi$?

Comment: This would be the case only if the scale factor is $\dfrac{1}{3}$

Comment: No, here it is assumed that the scale factor is positive.

Comment: Rotate the inner tetrahedron around an axis that goes through the midpoints of opposing edges. By symmetry, its vertices will hit the outer tetrahedron faces simultaneously. This reduces the problem to a 2D rotation of a line segment inside a rectangle. You should get something like $\sin^{-1} \frac{1-f}{2f}$ for the angle I think. Note that there are 6 ways to do this (3 axes to choose from, two directions of rotation). I don't know if there are any other rotations that also work.

Comment: Yes.  This makes sense.  I'll try it.

Comment: Aren't some scale factors ($<1$) "invalid," in the sense that the scaled tetrahedron simply cannot be placed as specified?  For instance, surely a scale factor of $0.0001$ is invalid.... no?

Comment: Yes. Of course.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  I've edited my question to explicitly specify the valid range for the scale factor.  Thanks for your remark.

Comment: It would really help if you could plot even a single example of what you're seeking.  I'm not convinced you can *ever* achieve what you seek.

Comment: I think @JaapScherphuis has solved the problem in his comment above.  I have verified that it does indeed result in the scaled/rotated tetrahedron having its four vertices on the four faces of the original tetrahedron.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Check the .GIF animation in my solution below.

Comment: I posted an answer to a related question which may be of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4391646/general-means-of-obtention-of-regular-tetrahedra-inscribed-into-a-regular-tetrah/4391802#4391802

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis See this follow up question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4391646/305862

Answer (score 1):

This is not my solution.  It is an implementation of the solution outlined by **Jaan Scherphuis** in his comment above.  I've verified the formula he provided and it does work.

Below is an animation that depicts the solution.

[image]

Comment: OK... great.  It *can* be done!  (+1 for the question).

Comment: [+1] Nice animation.

Comment: See this follow-up question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4391646/305862